# Tomcat + Spring MVC: CSS and Javascript are not loaded in SSL setting

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, ssl

I am using Tomcat (6.0.26) and Spring MVC for a website on Windows 7. I would like to test whether it works on SSL for certain pages or directories.

I have a self-assigned SSL certificate (file: .keystore) in C:\Users\Me with the default password "changeit".

In my Spring's security context, I have the following:

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" request-matcher="regex" >

    ....

    <intercept-url pattern="^\/login$" requires-channel="https"  />

    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
   </port-mappings>
</http>
```

When I click http://localhost:8080/login, I am redirected to https://localhost:8443/login, which works as I hoped for. However, only SOME, not all, css files get loaded and NONE of my javascript files get loaded. All my css and javascript files are local.

Here is how I have for css files in JSP:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

I have this in Spring context for CSS and JS files

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" /> 
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

Here is how I have for javascript files and what is shown in Firebug:

```
<script src="/js/my.js"></script>
this leads to Status being "302 Moved Temporarily". no file content is loaded

<script src="//js/my.js"></script>
this leads to Status being "Aborted"
```

What went wrong? How to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Where you added these css and js files outside or inside WEB-INF folder

Comment: css and js files are in the root the directory of the website. Not under WEB-INF. In my Spring context, I have something like this: <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />. CSS and JS files are working under HTTP. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

(1) Add this to your web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

(2) add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to your context

(3) try path as /yourApp/css/*.css

Comment: Thanks for your input. In web.xml, I already have <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>. Adding yours makes Tomcat unable to start.

Comment: can you please post log in detail. Perhaps your path is like /yourApp/css/style.css instead of /css/style. Try this and let me know

Comment: Are you using Tika & Solrj together?

Comment: Ghayel, I got it working now. I am not using Tika or Solrj. The initial cause for not loading css and js fiels may have been caused by incorrect roles used in other places. This is a pretty complex website. Thanks so much for trying to help me! I voted up your answer and comments.